# Fixed, keyboard layout-agnostic virtual key with Win32's WM_KEYDOWN

Tags: c#, .net-5, win32gui

2021-07-29:

I'm looking for a way to reproduce JavaScript's [`KeyboardEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#properties)'s behavior with Win32's `WM_KEYDOWN`:

> This ignores the users keyboard layout, so that if the user presses the key at the "Y" position in a QWERTY keyboard layout (near the middle of the row above the home row), this will always return "KeyY", even if the user has a QWERTZ keyboard (which would mean the user expects a "Z" and all the other properties would indicate a "Z") or a Dvorak keyboard layout (where the user would expect an "F").

so far, I've come pretty close to my goal by mapping the scan-code using `MapVirtualKeyEx()` with the default keyboard layout:

```cs
[UnmanagedCallersOnly(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(CallConvStdcall) })]
static unsafe nint WindowProc(HWND hWnd, WindowMessage msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
   if (msg is WindowMessage.WM_KEYDOWN)
   {
      var scanCode = (uint) (((nint) lparam) >> 16) & 0xFF;
      var keyboardLayout = User32.LoadKeyboardLayout("00000409", 0); // "00000409" is supposed to be the default layout.
      var inputDebug = ((VK) (nuint) wparam).ToString();
      var mappingDebug = ((Key) User32.MapVirtualKeyEx(scanCode, MapTypes.MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX, keyboardLayout)).ToString();
      //                    `-> where "Key" is my own "VK" enum, for the sake of naming convensions.

      Console.WriteLine("Input:  " + inputDebug);
      Console.WriteLine("Mapped: " + mappingDebug);
   }
   else if (msg is WindowMessage.WM_CHAR)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Char:   " + (char) (nuint) wparam);
   }
}
```

Which gives the following kind of log:

```
Input:  VK_UP
Mapped: ArrowUp

Input:  VK_CONTROL
Mapped: ControlLeft

Input:  VK_OEM_7
Mapped: Backquote
Char:   ²

Input:  A
Mapped: KeyQ
Char:   a
```

However, `LoadKeyboardLayout()`, which I use to get an `HKL` to the default layout, has an annoying propension to update the language input setting of the the entire system, which is defo **not** what I want...

[image: I need 10 reputation to post images. You'll have ASCII art instead:]

```
         _________________________________
        |  ENG   English (United States)  |
        |  FR    French keyboard          |
        |                                 |
        |  ENG   English (United States)  |
        |  US    US keyboard              |
        |                                 |
        |  AZ    Languate preferences     |
_________________________________________________
 ^  [/]:  ((.  <))  |░ENG/FR░|  2021-07-29  [, ]
```

And, I'm blocked there...

Is there a way to get an `HKL` representing the agnostic keyboard layout without actually loading it and changing the system's settings?

Or am I even looking in the right direction here?

---

2021-08-10:

- So far, I've been trying to use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.KeyboardLayoutId` instead of `LoadKeyboardLayout("00000409", 0)`, without success.
- I've also tried to build a pointer from low- and high-words, without success (`MapVirtualKeyEx()` returns `0`)
- I tried to get into the Chromium source code, but this looks waaay above my understanding threshold for now. Despite that, I (think I) found [the code responsible for creating the DOM keyboard event objects on the C++ side](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/d7da0240cae77824d1eda25745c4022757499131/third_party/blink/renderer/core/events/keyboard_event.cc#L145-L148), but the only other reference to this `KeyboardEventInit` pointer is a [forward class declaration](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/search?q=KeyboardEventInit), and no sign of any implementation for `KeyboardEventInit::Create()`...

Comment: Unrelated, but love the ASCII art 

Comment: Editing a question bumps it up my feed. Try adding some more details and debug notes

Comment: @ChiracPhantom you found the answer?

Comment: Alas not: for now, I've resorted to the method of loading-mapping-unloading the default (US) KB layout at each key press, which I find quite pathetic, but it allowed me to move forward. I was thinking about using scan codes directly, but the MS doc says it's not a stable thing, so I gave up in that. Still open for suggestions.